# Hiding parameters on url with nginx

Tags: nginx, url-routing

I have a website with this kind of adresses:

www.mydomain.com/user/userprofile/[userprofile1]?r=[login]&w=[encryptedpassword]

ie:

www.mydomain.com/user/userprofile/toto?r=reqqfdvca&w=skvlsqmg 
www.mydomain.com/user/userprofile/titi?r=re45a&w=slkvldfgmg 
www.mydomain.com/user/userprofile/tutu?r=reqq0krgca&w=s46893ls 
etc...

the parameters are important because there are credentials to access the website but I would like my adresses to look like:

www.mydomain.com/user/userprofile/toto
www.mydomain.com/user/userprofile/titi
www.mydomain.com/user/userprofile/tutu
etc...

I'm new with nginx, and my english is not perfect so please excuse my mistakes, also I'm not familiar at all with regex (that's why I'm writing this url-rewriting question).
but please does anyone have an idea on how to do that?

thanks

---

The point is that I'm afraid it won't be possible to POST these vars.
I mean: to access my website each user may scan a QR code.
This QR code contain a shortened url that redirect to this kind of url (those with credential)
My joomla website detects credential in the url and automaticaly logs the user in.

That's why i would like to hide this vars

Comment: If these are credentials, I would put these into the `body` (instead of the `head`) of the requests.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass those parameters in a hidden format using either POST or SESSIONS. 
They appear in the address because they are being passed using a GET request, it's good for debugging but not for long term use as they are easily copied and make it easy for someone to login as someone else.

Using POST or SESSIONS will make the URL appear as you want.

[HTTP Methods: GET vs. POST](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

Comment: I partially agree with this. Using a POST is ideal for login or information submission, but not general browsing. From memory, POST is for changing application state, GET is for viewing. So POST the login credentials, then use the session on the server to remember it, possibly with cookies to help.